# How to iterate dictionary in angular template?

Tags: angular, dictionary, angular2-template

In our angular application, from controller I have returned a dictionary. How can I display the same in html template using *ngFor?

Please anyone help to achieve the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a pipe that maps the object (dictionary) to an array 
containing of type :    `{ key: string,value: any }`

Somthing like this:

```typescript
@Pipe({name: 'mapToArray'})
export class MapToArray implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let arr = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      arr.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return arr;
  }
}
```

and use it like that in the html file:

```xml
<span *ngFor="let item of content | mapToArray">           
  Key: {{item.key}}, Value: {{item.value}}
</span>
```

Comment: I have imported the class.I am getting the below error:  The pipe 'mapToArray' could not be found.

Comment: you need to declare pipes just like components inside the decleration array in your module

Comment: I use this solution but get error 'error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1' on mapToArray in html file. how to solve this error?

Comment: @HessamHosseini: you can change the signature of transform: transform(value, args?: any) so that args become optional. 
Also change the declaration of arr to : 
let arr : any[] = []; to prevent this error "Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'."

Answer (score 49):

You can use the built-in keyvalue pipe like this:

```xml
<span *ngFor="let item of content | keyvalue">           
  Key: {{item.key}}, Value: {{item.value}}
</span>
```

Comment: I like this answer better than the voted one since it's using built-in feature +1